# Showing the sequence of $x_n$ is unbounded, where $\forall n\geq 1$: $x_{n+1} = x_n + 1/x_n^2$ and $x_1 = 1$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, real-numbers

I somehow wish to exploit that monotone and bounded sequences converge.

We can observe that for each integer $n \geq 1: \ \ x_n \geq 1$.

*Induction*: This is true for $n = 1$, and assuming it is true for $n = p \geq 1$ we know

$$ x_{p+1} = x_p + \frac 1{x_p^2} \geq x_p \geq 1 \ . $$

We also see readily that it is increasing, namely $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac 1{x_n^2} > x_n \geq 1 $.

So we have an increasing sequence that is bounded below. What remains to examine is if the sequence is bounded above.

Suppose the sequence is bounded above by $M \in \mathbb{R}$. Then the set of points from the sequence is non-empty and bounded above, which furnishes a supremum $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$. The sequence must converge to $\lambda$ (by theorem of monotone and bounded sequences).

But then:

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \bigg( x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac 1{x_n^2} \bigg)\ \ \text{ tells us that } \ \ \lambda = \lambda + \frac 1{\lambda^2} \ . $$

This implies $\displaystyle \frac 1{\lambda^2} = 0$, which is not satisfied for any finite real number $\lambda$. But it can be satisfied by infinitely large real numbers.

Notice $\lambda \geq x_n \geq 1$ so $\lambda \geq 1$ and thus $\lambda \neq -\infty$. This leaves $\lambda = \infty$. But then that implies $x_n \to \infty$, which contradicts that the sequence is bounded above.

Hence the sequence is not bounded above. $\blacksquare$

---

Is it airtight, or did I miss some detail? Thanks!
If there is a neater or more elegant way to do it, then I'd love to see it!

Comment: looks good to me!

Comment: This is ok, but you can simplify if an increasing sequence is bounded above it must converge, and since you proved there is no possible $\lambda$ then it is unbounded and the limit is automatically $+\infty$.

Comment: Very good. But there are no infinitely large real numbers.....$\Bbb R$ can be expanded to an ordered field $\Bbb R^*$ ("hyper-reals") that contains some things that are larger than any member of $\Bbb R$. But in $\Bbb R^*$ we still have $x\ne x+1/x^2.$

Comment: You proof is good. If you want to go further you can also deduce the asymptotic behavior of the series ($x_{n} = (3n)^{1/3} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-1})$), but this is not required to show that it diverges.

Comment: Thank you all!
@Winther Would you mind hinting on how you think one could go about deducing that asymptotic behaviour?

Comment: @Winther Do you mean $x_{n} = (3n)^{1/3} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-2/3}\,\ln n)$?

Comment: @ProfessorVector Yeah that is a more correct error term, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @ProfessorVector How can I show  $x_{n} = (3n)^{1/3} + \mathcal{O}(n^{-2/3}\,\ln n)$?

Comment: @kapython There are many techniques one can use (depending on how rigorous you want to do it). A very simple way to just see what the leading order term should be is simply to take an ansatz $x_n = Cn^k$ and Taylor expand $x_{n+1}$ and match coefficients. I would try to see similar questions for more info about how to do this, e.g. https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x_%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%3D%20x_n%20%2B%201%2Fx_n%5E2%24&p=1 (and also try searching for similar looking sequences and you will find plenty of matches)

Comment: Thank you! @ProfessorVector

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is generally fine. Some improvements were already mentioned in the comments:

- The fact that the sequences is bounded below is not needed.
- An increasing bounded sequence has a limit $\lambda \in \Bbb R$, so there is no need to consider the cases $\lambda = \pm \infty$.

An alternative approach is the following. Is is not necessarily “neater“ but gives a quantitative estimate. (“How fast does the sequence diverge to $+\infty$?”) Adding
$$
 1 = x_{p+1}x_p^2 - x_p^3 \le x_{p+1}x_p^2 - x_p x_{p-1}^2
$$
gives a telescoping sum:
$$
n-2 \le \sum_{p=2}^{n-1} x_{p+1}x_p^2 - x_p x_{p-1}^2 = x_n x_{n-1}^2-2 \le x_n^3 - 2 \\
\implies x_n^3 \ge n
$$
which shows that the sequence is unbounded and diverges to infinity at last as fast a $n^{1/3}$.

It might also be constructive to notice that the same approach holds for a much wider ranges of recursion formulae, e.g.
$$
 x_1 = 1 \,, \quad x_{p+1} = x_p + \frac{1}{g(x_p)}
$$
where $g(x)$ is continuous and positive for $x > 0$.

Comment: Wow thanks. What was your guiding mental process to write up those inequalities and produce that telescoping sum? I understand those inequalities (having inspected them carefully) but I don't see how I could have come up with that... What is more, I'm struggling to see how that sum telescopes, despite having written up a few intermediate terms. Would you mind elaborating?

Comment: @kapython: Well, it is a technique which I have seen before. The rough idea is to compare the sequence with the solution of the differential equation $y' = 1/g(y)$. – There was a typo which might have causes your problem with the telescoping sum, it is fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Raising the given recursion $$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac1{x^2_n}$$ to the third power, we get
$$x^3_{n+1}=x^3_n+3+3\,\frac1{x^3_n}+\frac1{x^6_n},$$ or, with $y_n=x^3_n$,
$$y_{n+1}=y_n+3+\frac3{y_n}+\frac1{y^2_n}.$$ So $y_{n+1}\ge y_n+3$, i.e. (by induction, since $y_1=1$) $y_n\ge3n-2$, and $y_{n+1}\le y_n+3+O\left(\frac1n\right)$, i.e. $y_n<=3\,n+O(\ln n)=3\,n\left(1+O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)\right)$. Together, this gives $$x_n=(3\,n)^{1/3}\left(1+O\left(\frac{\ln n}{n}\right)\right)=(3\,n)^{1/3}+O(n^{-2/3}\ln n).$$

Comment: Can you explain how you got y_n >= 3n - 2?

Comment: Wow, will definitely have to think through this one slowly. Thank you!