# Question on sequences(Real Analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_1$ = 1 and $x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{1}{x_{n}^2}$.

Show that (a) $x_{n+1}^3 > x_{n}^3 + 3, \forall n > 1$, (b) $x_n \geq \sqrt[3]{3n-2}, \forall n > 1$, (c) Show that $x_n$ diverges.

I've done part a, but completely stuck for more than 2 hours on part b. If I hopefully understand part b, I'll try to do part c.

Comment: Part (c) follows from (b). Part (b) follows by induction from part (a).

Comment: What have you tried? [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3849085/showing-the-sequence-of-x-n-is-unbounded-where-forall-n-geq-1-x-n1) is another question on this sequence asked today.

Comment: I'm completely stuck on part b, I don't know how part b follows from part a.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof of (a):**

$x_{n+1}^3=\left(x_n+\dfrac{1}{x_n^2}\right)^3=x_n^3+3+\dfrac{3}{x_n^3}+\dfrac{1}{x_n^6}>x_n^3+3\;,$

for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

**Proof of (b):**

First we prove (b) for $\;n=1\;:$

$x_n=x_1=1\ge\sqrt[3]{3\cdot1-2}=\sqrt[3]{3n-2}\;.$

Now we suppose (b) is true for $\;n\;$ and prove it for $\;n+1\;:$

$x_{n+1}\underset{\overbrace{\text{From (a)}}}{>}\sqrt[3]{x_n^3+3}\underset{\overbrace{\text{Supposing (b) true for $n$}}}{\ge}\sqrt[3]{3n-2+3}=$

$=\sqrt[3]{3(n+1)-2}\;.$

By induction (b) is true for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;.$

**Proof of (c):**

Since $\;x_n\ge\sqrt[3]{3n-2}\;$ for all $\;n\in\mathbb{N}\;$ and

$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt[3]{3n-2}=+\infty\;,\;$ it follows that $\;\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n=+\infty\;.$